# How to search through a database using WPF and display the results in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to search for a purchase from my database, from the 'PurchaseTable' table and display the results in a DataGrid, I know how to do it using Windows Forms:

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TitleOfRecord, DateOfPurchase FROM  PurchaseTable WHERE (NameOfCustomer = '"+NameOfCustomerSText.Text+"')", connection);
        //Query that will return the Title of the Records and Dates of purchases depending on the Customer which has been searched for
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        PurchaseResults.DataSource = dt;
        //Results will appear in the PurchaseResults DataGrid
    }
```

but I don't know how to do it with WPF, so far I have this but it does not work:

```
private void SearchCustomerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TitleOfRecord, DateOfPurchase FROM  PurchaseTable WHERE (NameOfCustomer = '" + NameOfCustomerSText.Text + "')", connection);
        //Query that will return the Title of the Records and Dates of purchases depending on the Customer which has been searched for
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        PurchaseResults.DataContext = dt;
        //Results will appear in the PurchaseResults DataGrid
    }
```

I have these namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

I used this code to solve my problem:

```
private void SearchCustomerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TitleOfRecord, DateOfPurchase FROM  PurchaseTable WHERE (NameOfCustomer = '" + NameOfCustomerSText.Text + "')", connection);
        //Query that will return the Title of the Records and Dates of purchases depending on the Customer which has been searched for
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        PurchaseResults.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        //Results will appear in the PurchaseResults DataGrid
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection: it's practically begging to get hacked. Before you do anything else, you need to research how to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using code behind then you should provide DataGrid's `ItemSouce` but when dealing with Binding with MVVM Architecture then `DataContext` is used.

so replace

```
PurchaseResults.DataContext = dt;
```

to

```
PurchaseResults.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I tried that and received this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: sorry to bother you once again, now when I search with valid criteria I only see one white area in the datagrid, the TitleOfRecord and Date columns are not being displayed

Comment: Set its `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`.

Comment: thank you for the help, I've got most of it working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
PurchaseResults.DataContext = dt;
```

to

```
PurchaseResults.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I tried that and received this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I'm not able to try it here right now, and I'm not sure why you get this error. But you can try using dt.DefaultView instead of dt for ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the columns in the data grid. If not WPF can automatically generate it for you when you set the AutoGenerateColumns property to true.

```
PurchaseResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
PurchaseResults.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
PurchaseResults.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

Comment: Hi, inputed the code but when I search with valid criteria I only see one white area/line in the datagrid, the TitleOfRecord and Date columns are not being displayed

Comment: @user2316176 : check PurchaseResults.AutoGenerateColumns and the binding of the itemsource in XAML

Comment: @user2316176 check this url http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html for Manually define columns if you want